# What is the proper time to eat Vitamin B2 and B6?

Tags: medications, effectiveness, time-of-day, meal, vitamin-b

I am usually told to take particular medicines before dinner or after dinner. Does this apply to  Vitamin B2 and B6?

More detailly,

1. Should I eat them in 30 minutes near dinner (after longer time, in shorter time, right after dinner or it doesn't matter ?)
2. Is it better to eat at other time than near dinner?
3. If I am not allowed to eat them near dinner, what time is second best to eat ? (Morning, Noon, Afternoon, Dusk, Night, MidNight ? specific range of a day would be better . )

There are many sites talking about this, such as https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/319556.php  (it suggest eat on an empty stomach in the morning, but also many sites says take 30 minutes after dinner ... )

But none of them provided an evident. I would be glad to see medical thesis, paper or credible research results.

Comment: I removed your second question, please ask that as a question of its own.